# VBA documents.count fails if word close before

Tags: vba, count, document

So when I use the code below with no word document open, I get a 0. So far so good. I open one word document and I get a 1. Up to here, all fine.

But when I close the word document, I get an error 462.
Click accept and it works normally again.

```
Sub test()
Debug.Print (Documents.Count)
End Sub
```

I want to automate some work by checking the amount of open word documents and don't want to get an error just because I closed the word application. And thankfully I managed to isolate the problem.

Please help. Much appreciated and thanks for your time.

Comment: Does `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` work for you?

Comment: I just tried using that with no luck, the error stops the code. The problem is still there after I closed the word document.

Comment: If all else fails bracket the line with `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0`. Avoid further use of this error bypass unless you know how to use it. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm